# Failed to install cordova-plugin-photo-library

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

IOS build failed with following error

Failed to install "cordova-plugin-photo-library":"CordovaError: Version of installed plugin:"cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^4.3.2'. Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency .

**Cli packages**
ionic/cli-utils:1.19.1
ionic (ionic CLI): 3.19.1

**Global Packages:**
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

**Local Packages:**

ionic/app-scripts: 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.4

**DEPENDECIES**

cordova-plugin-add-swift-support: 1.7.1
cordova-plugin-camera: 3.0.0
cordova-plugin-file: 6.0.1

Tried forcing ( cordova-plugin-file@4.3.2), got next error
Cannot find module'../cordova/platform_metadata'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/107#issuecomment-367320068
I updated plugin.xml with `<dependency id="cordova-plugin-file" version="6.0.1"/>` to fix this issue

Comment: Can u please let me know the location of plugin.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because I used plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer", so both of them use cordova-plugin-file => conflict.
I solve it by those steps below: 
1. Remove plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer":

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

2. Add plugin "cordova-plugin-photo-library"

```
ionic cordova plugin  add cordova-plugin-photo-library
```

3. Re-add plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer":

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

and run `ionic cordova prepare` to build sources.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with the File plugin. I had to match the version in plugin.xml (cordova-plugin-file) with the latest version. You will also need to review project.properties and build.gradle

Comment: Thank you for response. Problem not with android , this works fine on android , I was facing problem when trying to build for IOS. But finally I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to fork https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library
and then execute "cordova plugin add yourgiturl"
You can use https://github.com/tudordumitriu/cordova-plugin-photo-library

Answer (score 0):

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module
>   '../cordova/platform_metadata' error.
>
> It was a bug in in cordova-plugin-add-swift-support, you just need to
>   update it to its latest version
>
> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support

Reference: https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/111